# Awk -v doesn't recognize line in txt file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to replace a string with a variable inside a while loop.

```
while read line; do
    export TEMP=$line
    snmpwalk -v 2c -c public $line 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14 > temp.txt
    awk -v text="IF-MIB:" -v replace="$TEMP" '{gsub(text,replace); print;}' temp.txt >> report.txt
done < $filename
```

The file I use is a list of IP addresses.
A sample of what is in temp.txt :

```
IF-MIB::ifInErrors.1 = Counter32: 0
IF-MIB::ifInErrors.2 = Counter32: 4
IF-MIB::ifInErrors.3 = Counter32: 4
IF-MIB::ifInErrors.4 = Counter32: 3
```

I want to replace "IF-MIB:" by the IP address (line of the file) and add the content to report.txt which is the result of all IPs.

I tried different solutions and right now I store the IP in a env variable because awk doesn't recognize $line. But this approach doesn't work either

When I run `awk -v text="IF-MIB:" -v replace="$TEMP" '{gsub(text,replace); print;}' temp.txt >> report.txt`
in shell I get the expected result :

```
172.16.0.1:ifInErrors.1 = Counter32: 0
172.16.0.1:ifInErrors.2 = Counter32: 4
172.16.0.1:ifInErrors.3 = Counter32: 4
172.16.0.1:ifInErrors.4 = Counter32: 3
```

When I do the same command in my script I get the following :

```
:ifInErrors.1 = Counter32: 0
:ifInErrors.2 = Counter32: 4
:ifInErrors.3 = Counter32: 4
:ifInErrors.4 = Counter32: 3
```

Comment: There is no need to `export` the variable unless `snmpwalk` specifically requires this variable somehow. Generally the purpose of `export` is to make the variable visible to child processes.

Comment: What happens if you hardcode the value of `replace` in your script? (`awk -v text="IF-MIB:" -v replace="172.16.0.1" ...`)  Or looking at from the other side, if you `echo "$TEMP"` in your while loop do you see the value you expect?

Comment: Also, can you do a `cat -t $filename` and tell us what you see? Any chance the file has DOS (^M) line endings?

Comment: tripleee : indeed but I tried everything I could to solve the issue

Comment: jas: this was actually the issue ! I did "cat -t" and the file had "^M" at the end of each lines. I recreated a new file and now it works. Thank you a lot (can I mark a comment as solution ?)

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. In the future, please consult https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info 'Before asking about problematic code' for the top 10 scripting problems. Your's was #1 in that list. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm really surprised because I didn't know about this even after following many bash lessons at university, this was never mentionned.

Comment: You have several other common issues in your script (e.g. missing `IFS=` before the read, missing quotes around shell variables, missing `&&` between commands, unnecessary export, etc....). Lurk around here for a while and browse the bash FAQ at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is easier and more efficient:

```
while read line; do
    snmpwalk ... | sed "s/IF-MIB:/$line/" >> report.txt
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: I tried it and it gives the same result. When I do it in command line (outside of my script) it works. But in my script the "$line" isn't recognized... I tried with an env variable aswell. If I "echo $line" in the "while", the IP is displayed...

Comment: Please show the first few lines of your script by editing your question.

Comment: The issue has been solved by jas, the problem was in the file that I was using and not in the script. But thank you for giving me an easier and lighter way to do it, I changed the line with yours in my script